# Fluent Nhibernate: SQLite, rollback in the end of nunit test

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate, nunit

I want to test that the persisting is working, but the changes cannot affect anything in the production database (sql server database).

Therefore i'm thinking of have a sqlite in-memory database as test database to try the persisting in a transaction and at the end of the test do a rollback.

Is this possible ? And how to do this? doesn't NUnit 2.6.2 got a rollback attribute or TransactionScope ?

EDIT:

Or do i really need to do like this in each test:

```
   [Test]
    public void TestPersistPerson()
    {
        using (var transaction = _inMemoryDatabase.Session.Transaction)
        {
                transaction.Begin();
                _inMemoryDatabase.Session.Save(new Person("Name"));
                transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You want to make some changes to database schema without affecting data from database?

Comment: This is a common approach to follow. I've had issues with NHibernate using nested transactions though (it might be me). If you're going to use a single transaction each time no worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case for the `[SetUp]` and `[TearDown]` attributes.

```
private ITransaction _transaction;

[SetUp]
public void StartTransaction()
{
    _transaction = _inMemoryDatabase.Session.Transaction
    _transaction.Begin();
}

[TearDown]
public void RollbackTransaction()
{
    _transaction.Rollback();
    _transaction.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it does exactly like the code i posted above. As i asked, isn't there any other way to do this ? Wasn't there a rollback attribute earlier in nunit ?

Comment: I am not aware of such an attribute. It seems you were asking how to avoid doing the transaction logic in each and every test. With the code above the transaction begin and rollback is done automatically before and after each test is run in your fixture. Also you could create a base fixture with these `SetUp` and `TearDown` methods and derive from this to split your tests into multiple fixtures without having to replicate this logic.